# Bootstrap/jquery click to show multiple hidden rows in a table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried several different solutions to this [found here on stack exchange] but seem unable to get my example working.

How do I set this table up so that clicking on the 'clickable' TR shows all the hidden rows after it?

here is the [condensed] table, note it's bootstrap3 'hover' type:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover dashboard">

    <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class='clickable' id="68" >
            <td>visible row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse out budgets" id="68collapsed">
            <td>hidden row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse out budgets" id="68collapsed">
            <td>hidden row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class='clickable' id="69" >
            <td>visible row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse out budgets" id="69collapsed">
            <td>hidden row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse out budgets" id="69collapsed">
            <td>hidden row</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the bit of JS I'm using to [try] to reveal the hidden rows.

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var target = '#'+id+'collapsed';

    if($(target).hasClass("out")) {
        $(target).addClass("in");
        $(target).removeClass("out");
    } else {
        $(target).addClass("out");
        $(target).removeClass("in");
    }
});
```

Clicking on the 'clickable' row, only shows the first [or maybe last] hidden TR.

Comment: Your [links] don't link to anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `data-toggle='collapse'` and `data-target`. Also, use class instead of id on the child rows.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="68" data-target=".68collapsed">
        <td>visible row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse out budgets 68collapsed">
        <td>hidden row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse out budgets 68collapsed">
        <td>hidden row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="clickable" id="69" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".69collapsed">
        <td>visible row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse out budgets 69collapsed">
        <td>hidden row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse out budgets 69collapsed">
        <td>hidden row</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/3FKaTSrWEA

Comment: Perfect, and simple I like :)  odd thing tho, while the rows 'reveal' themselves instantly, after clicking to hide them again they don't close until after about a second pause. any thoughts behind that?

Comment: Yes. It's because of Bootstrap's transition animation on the 'collapsing' class. You can speed it up by decreasing the time on the effect: `.collapsing{
  -webkit-transition:height .01s ease;
   transition:height .01s ease
}` I updated the demo: http://www.bootply.com/122870

Comment: @Zim May I ask why you rejected the suggested edit? I do not see a functional difference, except that this link might break again at some point.

Comment: @JanWichelmann it looked like the references weren't correct in the snippet. I updated again and added an SO snippet.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the same `id` on multiple rows. Assign 68collapsed, 69collapsed as class and not id.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y6Y6/

Basically, `id` is meant to uniquely identify an element. So your current JavaScript only picks up the first element with the id and changes it.

The relevant changes are:

```
<tr class="collapse out budgets 68collapsed">
```

(same for all tr's)

and then the line in the js:

```
var target = '.'+id+'collapsed';
```

`.` instead of `#` to indicate its a class not an id.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.clickable').show();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: @Blazemonger, he wants to show all rows after the clicked one, it will not show all if I click on the first row after your edit?

Comment: I don't think he literally meant "all rows". I might be wrong about that.